# Java Files.getFileAttributeView creation timestamp precision not milliseconds on ext4

Tags: java, ubuntu

I am trying to get sub second precision on my creationTime in Java. Here is my code:

```
Path path = Paths.get("path/to/file");
BasicFileAttributes attributes = Files.readAttributes(path, BasicFileAttributes.class);
FileTime creationTime = attributes.creationTime();
```

I am receiving a FileTime with just seconds precision.

I am running on Ubuntu 14.04 EXT4

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out. I switched to OpenJDK 1.8.0 and it works flawlessly. Previously I was using the Oracle distrib.